# How do I get the exact position of every ListView item in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get the exact position of every item in my ListView and have so far used GlobalKeys and RenderBoxes to get those coordinates. Unfortunately, every time I scroll and rebuild the ListView I get the infamous `Null check used on a null value` and the positions list is always empty. Interestingly enough, I get no errors during the first build.

I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.

Here's the code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late Offset itemPosition = const Offset(0, 0);

  late ScrollController _controller;

  List<double> positions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController(); // Initializing ScrollController
    _controller.addListener(() {
      _scrollListener();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    positions.clear();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        cacheExtent: 0,
        controller: _controller,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          GlobalKey itemKey = GlobalKey();
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
            RenderBox renderBox =
                itemKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            itemPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
            positions.add(itemPosition.dy);
          });
          return Container(
            key: itemKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Text(
                  "index: $index itemPosition: ${positions.isEmpty ? 0 : positions[index]}"),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a print statement in the listener you'll see that you're calling `setState` hundreds of times a second when you're scrolling. This is rebuilding the entire page every time for no reason.

If you remove that and remove the `positions.clear()` the error should go away and you'll at least start seeing values in the UI when you scroll.

That's not a complete solution, but it should get you going in the right direction.

I recommend the [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) package as it has more functionality that you'll find useful here.